# is Provider-Driven Contract Testing possible with pact?

Tags: pact

Is it possible with pact to let the provider create the definition of the contract and share it with consumers?

Answer (score 1):

Not yet, take a look at [this article](https://pactflow.io/blog/the-curious-case-for-the-provider-driven-contract/).

I'd advise Spring Cloud Contract for the provider driven approach.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I saw the article. I think it would be useful to know how to manage situations where many consumers define the contract and the only provider has to be compliant with all of them.

Comment: I would advise explicitly declare all the consumers inside VersionsSelector annotations and JVM parameter consumer_version_selectors https://docs.pact.io/pact_broker/advanced_topics/consumer_version_selectors/


In order to align the Pact it self call everyone who is interested to the consumer pull request to review and approve the contract

Answer (score 1):

First of all, no, it's not currently possible to have the provider generate a contract and share it with consumers. We are [working](https://github.com/pactflow/roadmap/issues/4) on that at Pactflow.

> I think it would be useful to know how to manage situations where many consumers define the contract and the only provider has to be compliant with all of them.

1. In most cases, it's not an issue - consumers generally use your API in very similar ways (especially when retrofitting)
2. In the consumer-driven sense, it's rare to have multiple consumers driving design of the API at the same time - it's usually just one that's helping create the initial shape
3. If consumers start having very different (potentially conflicting) needs of a provider, then perhaps there is a genuine case to split the provider into multiple services.
4. The provider is also free to reject any requests (i.e. contracts with new/different expectations) from consumers.

Comment: Thank you, Matthew,
I think I'm starting to imagine the scenario you are referring to: probably consumers and providers developed by teams that have some connection to each other (e.g. two business units within an organization, but not limited to only this case)

The scenario I was thinking about for a Provider-Driven approach is quite different: a service used by hundreds of consumers worldwide.

I will wait for https://github.com/pactflow/roadmap/issues/4
I think it will be and interesting point of view

Answer (score 1):

Another way to look at this is by **leveraging API Specifications** such as [OpenAPI](https://www.openapis.org/) (which represents the Provider's API) **as the API Contract** with
[Contract Driven Development](https://specmatic.in/contract_driven_development.html). Here is a short [explainer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3HPgpvd8MGg&list=PL9Z-JgiTsOYRERcsy9o3y6nsi5yK3IB_w).

Rough outline of the approach

- OpenAPI specification representing your provider is run as [Contract as Test](https://specmatic.in/getting_started.html#provider-side---contract-as-a-test) against your provider application. With this you know that your provider is adhering to the Spec and it is safe to share with the consumers.
- The same OpenAPI specification can be leveraged as a [Stub](https://specmatic.in/getting_started.html#consumer-side---contract-as-a-stub--smart-mock) to emulate the provider for the consumers. This stub is truly representative of the provider because it is based on the mutually agreed OpenAPI Specification
- You can also maintain your API Specifications in a [Central Contract Repository](https://specmatic.in/documentation/central_contract_repository.html) (version control system such as Git) to make sure that consumers and providers are always referring to a single source of truth

**Contract Driven Development** suits all styles of development such as **Consumer First, Provider First and API First**.

Comment: I have explored specmatic for contract testing, but faced some challenges
- The realworld enterprise apis usually have many optional fields, you can express the different requests examples, but specmatic validates response only against the OpenAPI schema ! The schema validation alone does not help, a lot has been written about schema based contract testing and its limitation. see https://pactflow.io/blog/schemas-are-not-contracts/ 
- Specmatic does not use the examples defined in OpenAPI for stubs creation to serve consumers
- If # of query params is more, defining examples is cumbersome.

Comment: If you have existing test cases in `restassured` and/or mocks in `wiremock`, you can achieve the same schema-based contract testing using this library ->  https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/swagger-request-validator

Comment: @kiran thanks for exploring Specmatic. About "Specmatic does not use the examples defined in OpenAPI", we just released this - https://specmatic.in/documentation/service_virtualization_tutorial.html#examples-as-expectations. About defining examples for large number of parameters, we have VSCode extension that can generate examples - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KWCnTi-ifME&list=PL9Z-JgiTsOYRERcsy9o3y6nsi5yK3IB_w&index=2. Also now you can externalise tests as JSON - https://specmatic.in/documentation/contract_tests.html#externalized-test-data. Give it a try and let us know your thoughts.

Comment: thanks @HariKrishnan, It's good to see specmatic evolving rapidly with good features. One of the key and core feature that is non-negotiable for me is the validation of the actual response as per the example used in the contract definition. When I tried last time, the specmatic only validated response against the OpenAPI, not against the example response, which are created to validate the potentially different scenario combining the many optional fields to match the business logic.

Comment: @kiran We have recently launched the ability to verify responses against examples in OpenAPI spec. Here are the details - https://github.com/znsio/specmatic/discussions/1029.